# ggplot with extreme values

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: ggplot bar graph]

Have two questions -

1.What could be the best way to show / compare extreme values. The T group in the graph has value but no where close to the other groups, M & F

2. Is the way I can show proper number on the Y axis without having to divide them by 1000s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume a data.frame like the following:

```
#big values ranging from 10 to 100000 which would normally
#result to 10 not being shown
df <- data.frame(names=letters[1:3], values=c(100000,1000,10))
```

You can specify a log scale axis so that you can see both big and small values (uses log distance on the y axis) and also specify `labels = comma` from the `scales` library inside the `scale_y_log10` function to print 'nice' numbers instead of scientific:

See the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) #you need this for labels = comma
ggplot(aes(x=names, y=values), data=df) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  #scale_y_log10 will log scale the y axis
  #labels = comma will create nice numbers
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That worked! I was missing the library(scales) and that did the trick.